# problem on applying liouville theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I am stuck in the following problem:

> Consider the following set
>   $$A=\{f:f \text{ is an entire function and}  |f(z)|\leq 10+ |z|^\frac{3}{2},f(\Bbb N )\subset \Bbb N\}.$$
>   Then cardinality of $A=$?

I just know that using extended Liouville Theorem ,$f(z)$ is linear. But how to proceed after this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using Cauchy's Integral formula for a certain derivative of $f$. Can you bound it?

Comment: The Count:i have still not got it...could you explain a bit more

Comment: having just reread the problem, I was mistaken. I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

You know that $f(z)=a+b\,z$ for some constants $a,b$. Set $z=0$. The condition $f(\Bbb N )\subset \Bbb N\}$ implies that $a\in\Bbb N$ and $a\le10$. Set now $z=1$. This gives $a+b\in\Bbb N$ and $a+b\le11$. Evaluating at the integer values of $z$ gives further restrictions on $b$. For instance, $z=4$ gives $a+4\,b\le 18$.

Comment: :thanks a lot for your answer...still,i am not able to get the answer..could you give the answer

Comment: Yes I could, but I will not. You have enough information now to find it yourself.